# Why does the javascript apply function work recursively?

Tags: javascript, overloading, apply

I am learning John Resig's javascript function overloading.

https://johnresig.com/blog/javascript-method-overloading/

I have a question while practicing the examples on this link:

```
function addMethod (object, name, fn) {
  var old = object[ name ]
  object[ name ] = function () {
    console.log(fn.length)
    console.log(arguments.length)
    if (fn.length === arguments.length) {
      let ret = fn.apply(this, arguments)
      console.log(ret)
      return ret
    } else if (typeof old === 'function') {
      let ret = old.apply(this, arguments)
      console.log(ret)
      return ret
    }
  }
}
```

`addMethod` is for function overloading, and the behaviour inside the actual function was when I called the function.

The question arises when the apply function is executed. 
If the function argument is different, the `old.apply` function is called. 
If this function is called, it works recursively.

For example, if there is no actual `function` argument, the first `argument.length` is 2 and `old.apply` is called. Again, in a recursively called function, the `arguments.length` value is 1. Why is the apply function recursively called?

ps.
`AddMethod`:

```
function Users() {}
addMethod(Users.prototype, 'find', function () {
  console.log('ARG 0')
  // Find all users...
})

addMethod(Users.prototype, 'find', function (name, age) {
  console.log('ARG 1')
  // Find a user by name
})
```

calling Function:

```
var users = new Users()
users.find() // Finds all
users.find('John') // Finds users by name
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it's recursively called"? Are you observing a recursion, or are you assuming that there will be recursion? What does the output of the above look like in your test?

Comment: right. I debugged and the apply function is called recursively.

Comment: i add my additional code. when i call users.find() function and different arguments.length(0) & fn.length(2), old.apply called. after then, fn.length is 1 and argument.length is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute

```
addMethod(Users.prototype, 'find', function () {...}
```

then `Users.prototype.find` is set to a wrapper function containing the function (fn) in the statement.

Then you execute

```
addMethod(Users.prototype, 'find', function (name, age) {...}
```

which shifts the previous wrapper function into the old variable and binds a new wrapper function to `Users.prototype.find`.

When you call `users.find()` (with no arguments) it seems as if you call your find function (containing the console.log statement), but in fact you call the last defined wrapper function bound to `Users.prototype.find`. The variables are printed. 
Since the arguments do not match, the wrapper function calls the old 'wrapper' function instead (helt in the `old` variable). The variables are printed a second time. Then the actual 'find' function as defined with `addMethod` is called.

This is not really recursive, you just stored two functions and the first (wrapper) function calls the second. Then it ends.